# Constantly interpolated splines

Tags: interpolation, curves, motion

Trying to implement a movement through a curve - I'm trying to find a type of curve/spline that interpolates constantly. What I mean: when I interpolate from t=0 to t=0.1, I want it be the same distance as when interpolating from t=0.1 to t=0.2. And I want it to happen for every delta t on the spline.

I dont' want to make lookup tables that map the interpolated values to distances in order to save the memory. Does anybod knows are there any kind of such mathematical constructs?

I could do a in depth research, but as far as I can, I dont wan go to deep into details. It would be great having some simple formula.

Comment: Constant velocity in general splines is a hard problem, so you may be out of luck looking for a  "simple formula". The simple fornulas available don't give constant velocity, and the methods that do give constant velocity aren't simple (eg.http://community.spinxengine.com/content/19-constant-speed-cubic-spline-interpolation.html )

Comment: This is not going to happen, there is no simple formula for what you are looking for unless it's a simple arc. What you can do is a form of quick binary search. That works great.

Comment: OK thx, I will figure out something. In the end I'm left with simple arcs or joined line segments or something in-between.